# how to specify a date and then use it with a time format defined using the package datetime

Tags: formatting, datetime

I have a document in which I have some date and time formats defined using the package [datetime](http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/datetime/datetime.pdf). Specifically, I have something such as the following in the preamble:

```
    \newtimeformat{RFStimeA}{\twodigit{\THEHOUR}\twodigit{\THEMINUTE}\twodigit{\THESECOND}}
    \newdateformat{RFSdateA}{\THEDAY~\monthname[\THEMONTH] \THEYEAR}
    \newdateformat{RFSdateB}{\THEYEAR-\twodigit{\THEMONTH}-\twodigit{\THEDAY} }
    \newdateformat{RFSdateTimeA}{\THEYEAR-\twodigit{\THEMONTH}-\twodigit{\THEDAY}T\RFStimeA}
```

These defined formats can be used in the document in a manner such as the following:

```
This document is for the date \RFSdateB\today.
```

This setup works fine if the date to be typeset in the document is the current date. What I need to be able to do is switch between current dates and specified dates in a manner such as the following (in the preamble):

```
% Set the date.
    % Define the date.
        \date{2013-09-08}
    % Use today's date.
        %\date{\today}
```

What code should I use in the document (in place of something such as `\RFSdateB\today`) in order to be able to cope with such a 'switch' in the preamble? How should I specify the date in the preamble? Thanks for any ideas you may have!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a new date using `\newdate{<datename>}{<year>}{<month>}{<day>}` and retrieve it with `\displaydate{<datename>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datetime}% http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime

\newtimeformat{RFStimeA}{\twodigit{\THEHOUR}\twodigit{\THEMINUTE}\twodigit{\THESECOND}}
\newdateformat{RFSdateA}{\THEDAY~\monthname[\THEMONTH] \THEYEAR}
\newdateformat{RFSdateB}{\THEYEAR-\twodigit{\THEMONTH}-\twodigit{\THEDAY} }
\newdateformat{RFSdateTimeA}{\THEYEAR-\twodigit{\THEMONTH}-\twodigit{\THEDAY}T\RFStimeA}

\begin{document}
RFSdateA: \RFSdateA\today \par
RFSdateB: \RFSdateB\today \par
\newdate{mydate}{8}{9}{2013}%
RFSdateA: \RFSdateA\displaydate{mydate} \par
RFSdateB: \RFSdateB\displaydate{mydate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you very much for your assistance!